# Applying Custom Style to ASP.Net Calendar control

Tags: css, calendar

I want to apply custom css to my calendar control. I have applied the same at corresponding locations for e.g.

```
e.Cell.CssClass = "highlight";

clndrEvt.TodayDayStyle.CssClass = "currentDay";
clndrEvt.OtherMonthDayStyle.CssClass = "OOB";
clndrEvt.NextPrevStyle.CssClass = "dayTitle";
```

However when i render the control, my styles are not reflected.

When i check 'View Source' it applies my classes (italic) and ALSO applies in-line styles (underlined) along with it, which overwrites my styles. For example,

```
class="highlight" align="center" style="color:White;background-color:Silver;width:14%"
```

Can anyone help me out with this? To be very specific how to remove those in-line styles (by using which properties) from the HTML by settings properties of calendar control.

I have tried few, but that did not work.

```
e.Cell.Attributes.CssStyle.Clear();
e.Cell.Attributes.Add("Style", string.Empty);

clndrEvt.Style.Clear(); // clndrEvt is my calendar control
```

Comment: can you also post the code on your aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with a project I had inherited. I worked out that the styling was being added via the `Master.skin` in `app_themes`. Might be worth a check there.